# Unable to get focus on Textbox when bootstrap modal popup opens

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

Hii I want to get focus on input textbox when the bootstrap modal popup opens

```
<div class="modal fade nopading" id="myModalpop" role="dialog">
    <div class="model-area">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-head">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="~/Content/images/logo.png" alt="Ova" style="float: left; padding-top: 10px;"></a>
                <form class="form-inline md-form form-sm mt-0" style="text-align: center;" method="get" action="@Url.Action("Review", "Product")">
                    <a href"#"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <input name="id" class="form-contro form-control-sm ml-3 w-75 wow fadeInRight animated" id="txtsearch"  type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                </form>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 0px;">
                @*<p class="links_p wow fadeInRight animated">QUICK LINKS</p>*@

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- end navbar-cell -->
```

I have applied javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myModalpop').on('show.bs.modal', function () {

        $('#txtsearch').focus;
        //$(this).find('#txtsearch').focus();
     });
});
</script>
```

Focus on textbox

Comment: you can refer this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: No this Link is only about focus on textbox on click on textbox but I want that it shows focus in textbox when modal opens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions to solve this issue

first one is using `setTimeout` function to set focus your textbox within `'show.bs.modal'` event because this event is fired before model shown as following

```
$(function () {
    $('#myModalpop').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
          setTimeout(function(){ $('#txtsearch').focus(); }, 300);         
     });
});
```

second solution is using `'shown.bs.modal'` event which fired after modal shown but you should remove class `fade` from you model as following:

```
$(function () {
    $('#myModalpop').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { 
        $('#txtsearch').focus();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
<div class="model-area">

'show.bs.modal'
```

change to

```
<div class="modal-dialog">

'shown.bs.modal'
```

Notice **model** and **modal**

---

Did you missed the bracket?

```
$('#txtsearch').focus();
```

Comment: yes it's working but it is affecting my project design

Comment: probably need also change css accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Called with selected popup id.

```
$('#myModalpop #txtsearch').focus();
```